# How to use different styles for android and ios on react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to use different styles for ios and android, how can I do it?
And maybe somebody know how to stylizing TextInput, I need only bottom border, but borderBottomWidth doesnt work.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. The simplest one in your case would be to use Platform.OS:

```js
var {Platform} = React;

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    height: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 200 : 100
});
```

Comment: here: https://github.com/emilioicai/react-native/blob/master/docs/PlatformSpecificInformation.md

Answer (score 11):

From https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code, you can use `Platform.select`

> There is also a Platform.select method available, that given an object containing Platform.OS as keys, returns the value for the platform you are currently running on.

```
import { Platform, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        backgroundColor: 'red',
      },
      android: {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
      },
    }),
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import { Platform, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    logo: {
        width: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 80 : 100,
    }
});
```